# Django-Filebrowser settings not defined

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

Quick (probably silly) question regarding Django-Filebrowser.  I'm adding the lines from readthedocs in my settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_ROOT", settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and I'm getting

```
NameError: name 'settings' is not defined
```

If I'm right, adding an import

```
import filebrowser.settings
```

Will throw a circular reference error (it comes up asking for a SECRET_KEY) if I do so.  What do I do to fix this and define settings?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at [the source](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser/blob/master/filebrowser/settings.py) it looks like you should import Django settings:

```
from django.conf import settings
```